# Java Binding library exception in Xamarin

Tags: android, xamarin

I Started creating binding library for one of the Java SDK s and managed to successfully map most of the code, but I faced with one particular problem which took me more than 3 days before I opened this thread.

Problem is that I wanted to create Binding library for Kontakt.io android SDK for this I created project added tow jar files (core and android SDK are both of their SDK parts) and set build action to InputJar created mappings for all members and interfaces but now I have a problem where I overload in Java code but generator can not generate appropriate types for method which results in generating duplicated code generation and project does not compile.

Here is my Metadata.xml

```
  <attr path="/api/package[@name='com.kontakt.sdk.core.interfaces.http']/interface[@name='ActionsApiAccessor']/method[@name='createAction' and count(parameter)=2 and parameter[1][@type='com.kontakt.sdk.core.interfaces.model.IBrowserAction'] and parameter[2][@type='java.lang.String']]" name="managedName">CreateAction</attr>

  <attr path="/api/package[@name='com.kontakt.sdk.core.interfaces.http']/interface[@name='ActionsApiAccessor']/method[@name='createAction' and count(parameter)=2 and parameter[1][@type='com.kontakt.sdk.core.interfaces.model.IContentAction'] and parameter[2][@type='java.lang.String']]" name="managedName">CreateAction</attr>
```

and this is what gets generated on c# code.

```
    // Metadata.xml XPath method reference: path="/api/package[@name='com.kontakt.sdk.core.interfaces.http']/interface[@name='ActionsApiAccessor']/method[@name='createAction' and count(parameter)=2 and parameter[1][@type='com.kontakt.sdk.core.interfaces.model.IBrowserAction'] and parameter[2][@type='java.lang.String']]"
    [Register ("createAction", "(Lcom/kontakt/sdk/core/interfaces/model/IBrowserAction;Ljava/lang/String;)Lcom/kontakt/sdk/core/http/HttpResult;", "GetCreateAction_Lcom_kontakt_sdk_core_interfaces_model_IBrowserAction_Ljava_lang_String_Handler:Kontaktio.Core.Interfaces.IActionsApiAccessorInvoker, Kontakt.io.Droid")]
    global::Kontaktio.Core.Http.HttpResult CreateAction (global::Java.Lang.Object p0, string p1);

    // Metadata.xml XPath method reference: path="/api/package[@name='com.kontakt.sdk.core.interfaces.http']/interface[@name='ActionsApiAccessor']/method[@name='createAction' and count(parameter)=2 and parameter[1][@type='com.kontakt.sdk.core.interfaces.model.IContentAction'] and parameter[2][@type='java.lang.String']]"
    [Register ("createAction", "(Lcom/kontakt/sdk/core/interfaces/model/IContentAction;Ljava/lang/String;)Lcom/kontakt/sdk/core/http/HttpResult;", "GetCreateAction_Lcom_kontakt_sdk_core_interfaces_model_IContentAction_Ljava_lang_String_Handler:Kontaktio.Core.Interfaces.IActionsApiAccessorInvoker, Kontakt.io.Droid")]
    global::Kontaktio.Core.Http.HttpResult CreateAction (global::Java.Lang.Object p0, string p1);
```

Can anyone help me out there how to fix this problem?

Comment: It should work if you set different manged names. So instead of naming both CreateAction use CreateBrowserAction and CreateContentAction.